# Pandas groupy: retrieve columns on which data is grouped

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a `pandas` `GroupBy` object, for example, set up like so

```
group = df.groupby([['col_1', 'col_2']])
```

Is there any way to return the column names on which that data has been grouped e.g.

```
group.get_grouped_columns()
```

which might return

```
['col_1', 'col_2']
```

Comment: Haven't you just passed the same argument in groupby call?`group.exclusions` may also work'

Comment: That definitely answers my question as posted. What I hadn't banked on is that the result returns a `set` so input order is not enforced on output, which opens a new can of worms for me. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `keys`:

```
>>> group.keys
['col_1', 'col_2']
```

Answer (score 2):

`grouper` with `names`

```
group.grouper.names
Out[96]: ['col_1', 'col_2']
```